# How can I bridge these two loops?

Tags: edges, loop

Hope someone can help please.

Starting with a dirty 3d scan of an object (a thick walled container) I've remodelled the object with the aim of cleaning it up and making some adjustments. I've modelled the outside surface and the inside surface separately but I can't close the edges of the two shells. The image below show the edges of the inner and outer shells.[image: Inner and outer shell edges]

The edge of each shell has the same number of vertices / edges but the distribution of the vertices means that when I bridge the edge loops I get a lot of crossover in areas where there is more detail in one shell than the other. [image: Crossover in the corners]

I tried spacing the vertices and while this solves the bridging problem it introduces unacceptable distortion (see spaced image). [image: Loop tools / space]I've tried simply filling the space but the result is similar to bridging.

Is there any way of keeping the original outline of the two edges and filling the gap between them?

Is there any way that I can upload the blender model?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Hi :). Are you using a Subdivision Surface modifier? If not, there's no need to connect each pair of vertices. You can share the file through https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Do the two loops have the same number of vertices?  If so, enable loop tools and use it to bridge edge loops.  If you get odd behavior, adjust the parameters in the loop tools adjustment panel.  If they don't have the same number of vertices, and I suspect the don't, you can bridge segments at a time and then work out what to do with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [*F2*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/f2.html#f2) addon which is shipped with blender. Open preferences, and activate the addon there.

[image]

To use it, select two adjacent vertices, and press <kbd>F</kbd> and hold the <kbd>F</kbd> key. The script will do the rest.

See the gif below:

[image]

Comment: Note: This will only work if the two loops have an equal number of vertices.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input. Each edge has 250 vertices. F2 addon produces the same output as bridging. I haven't used subdivision  surface modifier but I need to make the model manifold so I do have to close these edges. As you can see, there is a collection of vertices in the corner on one edge and towards the centre of the end edge in the other. Blender wants to join a vertex in the corner of the outer edge with a vertex in the middle of the inner edge which effectively cuts / fills the corner.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that there isn't a functional solution to this problem and that I might have to settle for a 'dirty' solution. After the model has been created it will be output in .stl format for 3D printing. At that stage all I need is for the shape to be filled and placed in position on the floor. I'll have a go at dissolving the number of vertices in the crowded locations so that I still end up with the same number of vertices in each loop, just fewer of them and see if that helps. I've uploaded the model (I think) . Thanks again, please keep the ideas coming in...

Comment: I think the model is here https://pasteall.org/blend/5a70d529b1984233add3b09eea182776

Comment: well, it has same number of vertices but they are not evenly distributed as in @Timaroberts answer, they are actually randomly scattered... This wont work with any of those tries... You should clean that topology first and then try to fill it, Try to merge by distance until it is still the same shape and then clean the rest manually

Answer (score 0):

As MikoCG pointed out the vertices weren't evenly spaced, however, the issue isn't so much the lack of even spacing between the vertices but the lack of alignment between vertices in each of the edge loops. In the outer loop the vertices were crowded in the corner areas, on the inner loop the vertices are crowded along the short edges. This forced the bridge loop to reach across spaces that were not between (inside) the two edge loops.

The original edges were the result of the design process which created more vertices than were strictly necessary, particularly along some straight sections of the edges. The model was created using the 'curves to mesh' add on which converts joined bezier curves into a curved mesh. That addon is a very quick way of creating complex shapes but the end result can yield too many vertices than are strictly necessary in some areas.

To resolve the issue I just removed unnecessary vertices in the crowded straight sections, for example in each of the four corners of the outer loop and on the short ends of the inner edge loop. I then made sure that in the critical corners of the model I had an even number of vertices on each edge so that I could bridge them. Having sorted out the tricky corners I then set about bridging the longer edges which was pretty simple as there are far fewer vertices. The end result looks like this.[image: matching vertices number in the tricky corners and along gthe longer edges]

I'd hoped that there would be a nice easy way to do this but the end result was just a very manual process. I could probably have used the curves to mesh tool in a way that would have reduced the number of vertices but that too would have required quite a bit more work. I think this solution is the quicker of the two.

Thanks again to everyone for your help

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: A judicious use of the shipped add-on _Loop Tools_  > 'Space' might speed this work up.