# How can I quickly join edges/vertices with face

Tags: edges, faces

I'm newby to Blender and computer animation. Sometimes, I join vertices one by one to manually create 3D objects. First, I create borders of an object with vertices and edges, then join them with faces. When the time comes to join opposite edges with faces, it is pretty much time consuming process which would be great to automate. Please see the video what I mean.
[image]

So, I need to click every edge one by one and press `F` button every time.
**Is there a tool in Blender to join all opposite edges at once with faces, say if the number of edges equal from each side?**
I may have explained this a bit wrong but I hope you get the idea looking at the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I've found what I was looking for. **Bridge Edge loops** can be used. I saw it in this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taltUktxgPU

**Note**. Edge loops should be from one object. They can be connected in one object in `Object mode`, then select both and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

**Note2**. I don't know why but I cannot see **Bridge Edge Loops** in `Vertex Select` mode. When I go to `Edge Select` mode, it appears.

Comment: On Note2: You mean you cannot see it in the context menu when you right-click in the viewport? That's because it is exactly that: a context menu. Right-clicking in _Vertex Select_ mode brings up some general things and functions from the _Vertex_ menu at the top. Right-clicking while in _Edge Select_ mode shows functions from the _Edge_ menu. If you don't use the context menu but the _Edge_ menu at the top, _Bridge Edge Loops_ is available there even in _Vertex Select_ mode.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to enable the **F2 add-on** that comes with Blender.

Then you can **select just 2 vertices** (in *Vertex Selection* mode <kbd>1</kbd>) **or 1 edge** in (in *Edge Selection* mode <kbd>2</kbd>), **move the mouse cursor** in the direction where you want to create the faces and **press the <kbd>F</kbd> key** several times.

[image: animation, F2 add-on in action]

Because the mouse cursor is 2D on your screen, the direction can be ambiguous in 3D space and F2 can create unwanted faces. In this case, undo and try to rotate the 3D model or find a better spot for the mouse cursor.

Related question: [How can I bridge these two loops?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/247762/107598)